# What is a Simple Example for using the Boost Graph Library

Tags: c++, graph, boost

I am trying to use the [BGL](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html), I find the documentation precise but lacks more examples for simple cases. My goal is described below (after reading the documentation I still couldn't do this):

```
struct Vertex
{
    double m_d;
    std::size_t m_id;
};

//or

struct Vertex
{
    double m_d;
    std::size_t id() const;
};
```

**Goals**:

0. A directed graph G (what is the difference between a bidirectional and directed other than in_edges please?)
1. G can hold the vertex type Vertex.
2. get the vertex by id from G and change the value m_d in the Vertex struct when I want.
3. add, remove verticies and edges between verticies and also supports costs i.e. cost(edge).

Could you please write me an **example** on how to do this with BGL please? I beleive I need `MutableBidirectionalGraph`?

Comment: "I beleive I need MutableBidirectionalGraph" - your application (algorithms) define your requirements. What algorithms do you need?

Comment: You should look at the bundled properties docs https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html which contains a nice example.

Comment: @sehe Thanks for taking the time. I don't need any algorithms at the moment, but I need to represent a real life case which I described in my goal. I just want to know how it works, I can't even construct a graph :)

Comment: @ravenspoint Thanks very much, I am checking that now. I would appreciate if you coud please add an example for my specific case above, as I don't want to be missing something based on my readings, how do you construct a graph? Is there only two options: adjacency_list and adjacency_matrix? What are all these concepts I see in the book MutableBidirectionalGraph and ***how do we use them*** please. Thanks very much anyways :)

Comment: Just look at the bundled props example.  It has everything you need.

Comment: @ravenspoint Thanks so much. I do more want to understand the generic setup so I can do more smart things than the example above :) So I think the concepts are key component to understand what is happening. Maybe I just start small and learn with time :) Thanks very much!!

Comment: Yup. Everything I showed was under the concept for MutableBidirectionalGraph, although the property maps are described [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/property_map/doc/property_map.html) and the [bundles](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html) docs just linked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

0. > A directed graph `G`

   Straight-away:

   ```
   struct Vertex {
       double m_d  = 0;
       size_t m_id = -1;
       // or std::size_t id() const;
   };

   struct Edge {
       double cost = 0;
   };

   using Graph =
       boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, Vertex, Edge>;
   ```

   > *(what is the difference between a bidirectional and directed other than
   > `in_edges` please?)*

   There is no other difference, except of course the complexity guarantees
   for enumerating incoming edges, and a linear overhead upon insertion of edges
1. > `G` can hold the vertex type `Vertex`.

   See 0.
2. > get the vertex by id from `G`

   ```
       auto find_by_id = [&g](size_t id) -> Vertex& {
           auto vv = boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g));
           auto vd = find_if(vv, [&, id](auto vd) { return g[vd].m_id == id; });
           return g[*vd];
       };
   ```

   > and change the value `m_d` in the `Vertex` struct when I want.

   ```
   if (i_want()) {
       g[vd].m_id += 1;
   }
   ```

   Or,

   ```
   auto idmap = boost::get(&Vertex::m_id, g);

   if (i_want()) {
       idmap[vd] += 1;
   }
   ```

   or even

   ```
   put(idmap, vd, 42);
   ```

   or even more unmarked:

   ```
   get(boost::vertex_bundle, g, vd).m_id = 999;
   ```
3. > add, remove vertices

   ```
    remove_vertex(vd, g);
   ```

   > and edges between vertices

   ```
    clear_vertex(vd, g);
   ```

   > and also supports costs i.e. cost(edge).

   Wow that really has nothing to do with any of the above. But it's really the same as with vertex ids:

   ```
   if (i_want()) {
       g[ed].cost = new_cost;
   }
   ```

   Or,

   ```
   auto cost = boost::get(&Edge::cost, g);

   if (i_want()) {
       cost[ed] = new_cost;
   }
   ```

   or even

   ```
   put(cost, ed, new_cost);
   ```

   or even more unmarked:

   ```
   get(boost::edge_bundle, g, ed).cost = new_cost;
   ```

### Live Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08fa0e2ea96138aa)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct Vertex {
    double m_d  = 0;
    size_t m_id = -1;
    // or std::size_t id() const;
};

struct Edge {
    double cost = 0;
};

using Graph =
    boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, Vertex, Edge>;

using boost::make_iterator_range;

int main(){
    Graph g;
    auto v0 = add_vertex({0.1, 100}, g);
    auto v1 = add_vertex({0.2, 200}, g);
    auto v2 = add_vertex({0.3, 300}, g);
    auto v3 = add_vertex({0.4, 400}, g);
    auto v4 = add_vertex({0.5, 500}, g);
    auto v5 = add_vertex({0.6, 600}, g);

    add_edge(v0, v2, Edge{1.5}, g);
    add_edge(v1, v3, Edge{2.5}, g);
    add_edge(v4, v1, Edge{3.5}, g);
    add_edge(v2, v5, Edge{4.5}, g);

    auto idmap = boost::get(&Vertex::m_id, g);
    auto cost  = boost::get(&Edge::cost, g);

    auto find_by_id = [&g](size_t id) -> Vertex& {
        auto vv = boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g));
        auto vd = find_if(vv, [&, id](auto vd) { return g[vd].m_id == id; });
        return g[*vd];
    };

    print_graph(g, idmap, std::cout << "original: ");

    auto i_want = [](auto vd) {
        return (vd % 2); // when I want
    };

    for (auto vd : make_iterator_range(vertices(g))) {
        if (i_want(vd))
            g[vd].m_id += 1;
        if (i_want(vd))
            idmap[vd] += 1;
        //put(idmap, vd, 42);
        //get(boost::vertex_bundle, g, vd).m_id = 999;
    }

    print_graph(g, idmap, std::cout << "altered: ");

    clear_vertex(v3, g);
    remove_vertex(v3, g); // undefined behaviour unless edges cleared

    print_graph(g, idmap, std::cout << "removed: ");

    for (auto ed : make_iterator_range(edges(g))) {
        std::cout << ed << " cost " << cost[ed] << "\n";
    }

    for (auto ed : make_iterator_range(edges(g))) {
        cost[ed] *= 111;
    }

    for (auto ed : make_iterator_range(edges(g))) {
        std::cout << ed << " cost " << cost[ed] << "\n";
    }
};
```

Prints

```
original: 100 --> 300 
200 --> 400 
300 --> 600 
400 --> 
500 --> 200 
600 --> 
altered: 100 --> 300 
202 --> 402 
300 --> 602 
402 --> 
500 --> 202 
602 --> 
removed: 100 --> 300 
202 --> 
300 --> 602 
500 --> 202 
602 --> 
(0,2) cost 1.5
(3,1) cost 3.5
(2,4) cost 4.5
(0,2) cost 166.5
(3,1) cost 388.5
(2,4) cost 499.5
```

Comment: Thanks sooo much, so find by id has to do a lookup, what if I just save unordered_map from id to vertex and then I have the vertex without doing the find_if above, isn't that faster? Thanks sooo much again!!

Comment: I _knew_ you'd say that. You can do that. Whether it's faster depends on MANY factors. I just added a live demo. For more convenience: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%2B%22sehe%22+%2B%22internal_vertex_name%22
For performance: measure!